# Render Variable Form Fields

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to created a vehicle project and when I select a brand I would like it to only list the models associated with that brand within my form.

[image]

Currently, if I select a Make, all models from all other Makes also appear.
I would like to filter the options down to only the Models associated with that Make.

```
class CarMake(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
country_of_origin = CountryField(null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('make-profile', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class CarModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    make = models.ForeignKey('CarMake', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('model-profile', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify('%s %s' % (self.make, self.name))
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Would suggest using a Ajax call to make this easier. Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: You may be interested in: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html and https://htmx.org/

Comment: @AMG Thank You for that link.